How to force MongoDB to always use specific indexes with $or clauses in
I have a MongoDB collection items with the following indexes:
db.items.createIndexes([{ team: 1, a: 1 }, { team: 1, b: 1 }])
I inserted some test data like this:
db.items.insertMany([
  { team: 1, a: "valueA1" },
  { team: 1, a: "valueA2" },
  { team: 1, a: "valueA3" },
]);

I have a MongoDB query similar to:
db.items.find({
    team: [teamId],
    // dynamic query part
    $or: [{ a: [value] }, { b: [value] }]
})

My goal is to ensure the query always uses the team_1_a_1 and team_1_b_1 indexes, but the actual index selection changes depending on the query values and the dynamic part of the query.
For example, when I run the following query:
db.items.find({
    team: 1,
    $or: [{ a: "valueA1" }, { b: "valueB1" }]
}).explain("queryPlanner")

I get the expected result where both indexes are used:
"winningPlan": {
  "stage": "FETCH",
  "inputStage": {
    "stage": "OR",
    "inputStages": [
      {
        "indexName": "team_1_a_1",
        ...
      },
      {
        "indexName": "team_1_b_1",
        ...
      }
    ]
  }
}

However, for this query:
db.items.find({
    team: 2,
    $or: [{ a: "valueA1" }, { b: "valueB1" }]
}).explain("queryPlanner")

The result does not match my expectations:
"winningPlan": {
  "stage": "FETCH",
  "inputStage": {
    "stage": "IXSCAN",
    "indexName": "team_1_a_1",
    ...
  }
}

I understand that MongoDB sometimes chooses better indexes automatically. But in my use case, where I have over 100 million documents, the index selection has performance issues, and I frequently encounter the following error:
multiplanner encountered a failure while selecting best plan :: caused by :: operation exceeded time limit
I’m looking for a way to force MongoDB to always use  indexes in the $or clause, similar to how hint works, and skip MongoDB’s index selection process. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Why do you not simply use a hint?

Depending on your query pattern, you may find wildcard index useful too.

@WernfriedDomscheit I have tried it, but I found that hint can only specify a single index.

Can you try to change the order of index keys?
db.items.createIndexes([{ a: 1, team : 1 }, { b: 1, team: 1 }])

In this case, because both indexes have prefix key: team so Mongo will do auto-selection process.
If we reverse the key to specify the filter keys of $or at the prefix then mongo will know and pick the correct index.

Thank you, this is a great idea. I tried it out, but when using a non-existent value for field a as a filter condition like this,
db.items.find({ team: 1, $or: [{ a: "anyValue" }, { b: "valueB1" }] })
MongoDB still only uses a single index. What I want is to bypass MongoDB’s index selection process and always use the index I created for the $or clause
